# When is $C\text-\mathsf{dg\text-mod}$ determined by the connective base changes?

Tags: derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, differential-graded-algebras, derived-functors

I'm using cohomological gradings.
For $C\in k\text-\mathsf{cdga}$ (where $k$ can be taken of characteristic 0), a morphism $C\to A$ to a connective dg-algebra $A\in k\text-\mathsf{cdga}_{\leq0}$ induces a functor $\mathsf{Ho}(C\text-\mathsf{dg\text-mod})$ to $\mathsf{Ho}(A\text-\mathsf{dg\text-mod})$, where the modules are unbounded.

Is there a caracterisation of those $C$ such that the family of functors $$\{-\otimes^{\mathbb L}_CA\ |\ A\in k\text-\mathsf{cdga}_{\leq0},f:C\to A\}$$
is conservative, i.e. such that $M\in C\text-\mathsf{dg\text-mod}$ is uniquely determined (in the derived category) by the data of all those dg-modules $M\otimes^{\mathbb L}_C A$ for all connective commutative $k$-dg-algebra $A$ ?

Comment: Do you have any non-connective examples? I suggest you look at extensions of $C$ by $C[n]$, which will become trivial after base change for $n \ge 0$.

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question. I have many difficulties writing down the explicit problem, but as I see that your domain of research includes derived stacks, here is maybe a better question : given an unbounded cdga $B$, there is an associated derived stack $\mathbb R\mathrm{Spec}(C)$, that is of course not a derived affine scheme, but we can hope that for example, its quasi-coherent category may be exactly $C$-$\mathsf{dg}$-$\mathsf{mod}$, under some conditions on $C$. That's the thing I wanted to ask : when does that happen ?

Comment: What's the relation between $B$ and $C$? $\mathbf{R}Spec$ tends only to be defined for connective things. I think you're aiming for something like Toen's affine stacks.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to write $C$ everywhere. Yes indeed, but derived affine stacks in a way, because my site is $(\mathsf{cdga}_{\leq0})^{op}$ and the derived affine stack associated to $C\in\mathsf{cdga}$ is $\mathbb R\mathsf{Map}_{\mathsf{cdga}}(C,-)_{|\mathsf{cdga}_{\leq0}}$ (Toens's site is juste $(k-\mathsf{Alg})^{op}$)

Comment: So for $x$ of degree $2$, you're setting $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Spec} k[x,x^{-1}]=\emptyset$. I expect you need $C$ to be maps from that presheaf to $\mathbb{A}^1$, which would imply it's a (sifted?) homotopy limit of connective cdgas.

Comment: Yes, this is an example of a $C$ for which it's clearly not true. Thanks for that I'll see if this always works. I actually would like it to be true for $C$ of the form $\mathsf{Sym}_A(M)$ for $A$ a connective cdga and $M$ a perfect module on $A$, does it have a chance to work?

Comment: That example feels as if it should work. You can cook up a simplicial derived affine representing the sheaf (in fact, a derived stack) by taking $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Spec}$ of $\mathrm{Sym}_A(\sigma(M \otimes C_{\bullet}(\Delta^n))$ in simplicial degree $n$, where $\sigma$ is stupid truncation. Because these are all affine spaces over $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Spec}A$, it looks as if the higher gluing data should all be unipotent, so the stucture sheaf should generate perfect complexes globally, which is all you need.

Comment: "I expect you need $C$ to be maps from that presheaf to $\mathbb A^1$" : I don't see why these maps should have a cdga structure...?
For your last message : Are you using that the category of module over a derived stack is $F$ the holimit of the modules over $X_n$ for $X_{\bullet}$ a simplicial scheme which homotopy colimit is $F$ ? I read this in "Higher stacks" Toen but I coudn't find a reference. Also, I don't understand from "it looks as if the higher" to the end, sorry. I have very little experience in this field. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The cdga (or equivalently, simplicial commutative ring) structure on maps to $\mathbb{A}^1$ comes from the ring structure on $\mathbb{A}^1$ (it's a ring object in affine schemes). You can find explicit descriptions of quasi-coherent sheaves on derived stacks in terms of simplicial resolutions in my simplicial schemes papers.

Comment: Your paper Presenting higher stacks as simplicial schemes will really help me, thank you. It seems to be way more detailed than the introductions to DAG I found. Also, just to understand : you said that C should be the maps from RSpec C to A¹, which you just said form a simplicial algebra = connective cdga. But the goal is to have C non connective, so I don't see your first point.

Comment: Sorry, the first instance of maps from $F$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$ should have been $\mathbf{R}\Gamma(F,\mathcal{O})$, taken in the category of CDGAs. (Maps to $\mathbb{A}^1$ are given by the good truncation of that.) Given a simplicial derived affine resolution, you can compute the associated cdga by applying the Thom-Sullivan (a.k.a. Thom-Whitney)  functor to your cosimplicial connective cdga.

Comment: And my "Notes characterising higher and derived stacks" should give a more readable summary than "Presenting higher stacks as simplicial schemes".

Comment: I'm not sure of the definition of $\mathbb R\Gamma(F,\mathcal O)$ in this context but anyway. So if I understood well, in my case $F=\mathbb R\mathrm{Spec}(C)$ is a colimit of a simplicial affine derived scheme $\mathbb R\mathrm{Spec}(A_{\bullet})$ and thus $L_{qcoh}(F)\simeq \mathrm{holim}A\text-\mathrm{dg\text-mod}$ a model of which are the homotopy cartesian cosimplicial $A_{\bullet}$-modules, so I need to show that $C\to A_{\bullet}$ satisfies the decent condition (all that in the sense of HAG II 1.2.12.1.) ?

Comment: Last thing : in your expression of those $A_{\bullet}$, you seem to use that the adjunction $A\text-\mathsf{cdga}\dashv A\text{-dg-mod}$ is simplicial (because the $\Delta^n$ is inside the $\mathsf{Sym}_A$, why is that true ? Also, I found $\sigma(\mathsf{Sym}_A(M\otimes C_{\bullet}(\Delta^n)))$ instead of $\mathsf{Sym}_A(\sigma(M\otimes C_{\bullet}(\Delta^n)))$, and it doesn't seem to be the same thing, am I wrong ? Thank you again.

Comment: Given any model structure, you can calculate mapping spaces using cofibrant cosimplicial resolutions (see the framings section in Hovey's book), of which that is one; you don't need a simplicial model structure. $\sigma \mathrm{Sym} M$ isn't usually a quotient of $ \mathrm{Sym} M$, while $  \mathrm{Sym}\sigma M$ is the quotient killing the ideal generated by terms of strictly positive degree.